# Mann-whitney tesy error: group factor 2 levels?

Tags: r

I keep getting the below error:

```
y <- as.factor(data$Pos.44)
x <- as.factor(data$Neg.44)
wilcox.test( x ~ y,  
                 alternative='two.sided', 
                 paired=FALSE, var.equal = TRUE, 
               conf.level = 0.95)
```

> Error in wilcox.test.formula(x ~ y, alternative = "two.sided", paired = FALSE,  : grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels

I have tried turning the data into factors, as numbers and have told r that the header is TRUE.  Any ideas??

Here are some of the data.

```
Neg 44      Pos 44
13.8228455  7.126694925
13.8228455  8.402648457
13.8228455  8.402648457
6.85288518  12.27621627
9.232427575 
11.31157309 
195.5120218 
82.61317544 
9.751455813 
4.490663867 
7.732335943 
3.72520288  
17.51041865 
8.56912795  
17.59120857 
12.3571618
```

Comment: Can you please share data in a reproducible, "copy&paste"-able format? Use `dput` or the code to generate sample data. Also use the editing tools to properly format code, data and text.

Comment: For what I can understand, you don't need to turn your numeric variables into factors, what you need is [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format).

Answer (score 0):

Your format is wrong. The inputs to the Mann-Whitney test requires one column with values, and another column with a two level factor. You've tried to feed it two numeric vectors converted to factors. See the example below:

```
x=c(rnorm(50,0,1),rnorm(50,1,1))
y=rep(c('A','B'),c(50,50))
wilcox.test(x~y, alternative='two.sided',  paired=FALSE, var.equal = TRUE,  conf.level = 0.95)
```

Comment: Thanks.  So the script would be?  data <- read.csv("Relative.44.csv", header = T)
x <- as.factor (data$Neg.44)
y <- as.factor (data$Pos.44)
x=c(rnorm(50,0,1),rnorm(50,1,1))
y=rep(c('A','B'),c(50,50))
wilcox.test(x~y, alternative='two.sided',  paired=FALSE, var.equal = TRUE, conf.level = 0.95)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>% 
  gather(k,v) %>% 
  with(.,wilcox.test(v ~ k, data=., exact =F))

Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  v by k
W = 45, p-value = 0.2367
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Or visualize your data using a boxplot

```
library(ggbeeswarm)
library(ggsignif)
d %>% 
  gather(k,v) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(k,v)) + 
   geom_boxplot() +
   geom_beeswarm() + 
   ggsignif::geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("Neg44", "Pos44")))
```

[image]

Your data

```
d <- read.table(text="Neg44 Pos44
13.8228455  7.126694925
13.8228455  8.402648457
13.8228455  8.402648457
6.85288518  12.27621627
9.232427575 
11.31157309 
195.5120218 
82.61317544 
9.751455813 
4.490663867 
7.732335943 
3.72520288  
17.51041865 
8.56912795  
17.59120857 
12.3571618",header=T,  fill=T)
```